# Scroll TextView automatically to last line in Activity when just started

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, textview

On start of Activity I want TextView been scrolled down to possible last line.

Now when Activity starts I see TextView showing text from top.
How I can scroll TextView to the last line and start and show it from bottom?

The code I'm currently using

```
@Override
    protected void initUI(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        logTextView = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.text );

        ArrayList<Event> events = getAll();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64*1024);
        for (Event event : events) {
            sb.append( event.toString() );
            sb.append( "\n" );
        }

        logTextView.setText( sb );
        logTextView.setKeyListener(null);
        logTextView.setFocusable(true);
    }

int y = (textView.getLineCount() - 1) * textView.getLineHeight(); // the " - 5" should send it to the TOP of the last line, instead of the bottom of the last line
            int visible = logTextView.getHeight() - (2* logTextView.getLineHeight());
            if( visible < y ) y -= visible;
            logTextView.scrollTo(0, y);
```

Comment: use logTextView.post(runnable) where runnable's run method calls scrollTo method

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code after your data is added:

```
final ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview));
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The TextView in ScrollView simply not works.

Comment: @android.dk just do what i suggested in my comment above

Comment: this is for scrollview and the question is about textview

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the solution

Here is the code

```
@Override
    protected void initUI(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        logTextView = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.text );

        ArrayList<Event> events = getAll();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64*1024);
        for (Event event : events) {
            sb.append( event.toString() );
            sb.append( "\n" );
        }

        logTextView.setText( sb );
        logTextView.setKeyListener(null);
        logTextView.setFocusable(true);

//This line triggers textView to scroll all the way down to the bottom.
logTextView.setSelection(logTextView.getText().length());
    }
```